# How to evaluate pOptions object's success method's parameter when dataType is text?

Tags: oracle-apex

I am using `Oracle APEX 21.2.5`. I am trying to set dataType property's value to "text" instead of the default "json" when calling `apex.server.process` to call an on-demand process named "`AC`". The problem arises when I needed to evaluate the parameter's value of the "success" pOptions' object method. With json I could use `apex_json.open_object, .. write, and close_object` to return values from the process which the parameter of "success" method holds. For example, This is the code of the process....

```
DECLARE
N NUMBER; 
BEGIN
SELECT 1 INTO N FROM DUAL;
 apex_json.open_object;
 apex_json.write('result', 'ok');
 apex_json.close_object;
END;
```

And this is the code of the dynamic action that fires when a button is clicked...

```
 apex.server.process("AC", {pageItems: "#P1_DNAME, #P1_LOC" },

 {success: function(ppData) {

   if (ppData = "{result: 'ok'}") {console.log("yes"); }

 }

 });
```

As you can see, I could evaluate the value of "ppData" parameter. How can I return a text from the procedure to be able to evaluate it like I did with json dataType?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`pData` is a json object if `dataType: "json"`   and a string if `dataType: "text"`  . Note that in your code you're evaluating json as a string - that can be done a lot easier, see the json example below.

Here is an example of both JSON and Text.

##### apex.server process with JSON Response

Application process source:

```
DECLARE
BEGIN
    apex_json.open_object;
    apex_json.write('result', 'ok');
    apex_json.close_object;
END;
```

Dynamic Action javascript code:

```
apex.server.process(
  'getResultJSON',                                // Process or AJAX Callback name
  {},  // Parameter "x01"
  {
    success: function (pData) {             // Success Javascript
      if (pData.result == 'ok') {
          apex.item( "P51_SUCCESS_JSON" ).setValue("Result of JSON is OK !")
      } else {
          apex.item( "P51_SUCCESS_JSON" ).setValue("Result of JSON is Not ok :( !")
      }
    },
    dataType: "json"
  }
);
```

##### apex.server process with Text Response

Application process source:

```
DECLARE
BEGIN
  /* use prn to prevent newline after string (htp.p prints newline).
  */
  htp.prn('ok');
END;
```

Dynamic Action javascript code:

```
apex.server.process(
  'getResultText',                                // Process or AJAX Callback name
  {},  // Parameter "x01"
  {
    success: function (pData) {             // Success Javascript
      if (pData == 'ok') {
          apex.item( "P51_SUCCESS_TEXT" ).setValue("Result of TEXT is OK !")
      } else {
          apex.item( "P51_SUCCESS_TEXT" ).setValue("Result of TEXT is Not ok :( !")
      }
    },
    dataType: "text"
  }
);
```

Comment: Where does htp.prn and apex_json subprograms return their output? In memory? Or in DOM? Or else?

Comment: It's the response of the ajax call. Check the browser dev tools > network. When the ajax process is executed you'll see the response there.